# Date Issue with Localhost on running the website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date, localhost

I designed a Website which I configured in IIS. After running the website in localhost, in one form I will select date as `'03/06/2014'` i.e; `'3rd June 2014'`. And I am entering other details and saving. These details are displayed in the gridview. In this gridview, the date is displaying as `'03/06/2014'`. These details are displayed in gridview in another form also. But, here the date is displaying as `'06/03/2014'`. This problem is only till the 12th date. On entering the date as `'13/06/2014'` or next dates in the first form, I cannot save the details. This is the month-date issue, but I do not know how to resolve this? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: share code, how can we help? Also make sure you are converting the date format as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
In Web.config file, I added the following code.

```
<globalization
     requestEncoding="utf-8"
    responseEncoding="utf-8"
    culture="en-GB"
    uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

I got this from http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_25782987.html